# Wire that was stripped inline and loops over the side screw

Tags: electrical, wiring

I found a light switch that has a wire that was stripped inline and then loops over the side screw. The same wire is also connected to a second switch.

Is this allowed? I thought that normally, it would be pigtailed.

[image: Wire that was stripped inline and loops over the side screw]

Comment: I'd be worried about the paint on the wire more than that it's stripped inline.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any code violation that says you can't do it, just so long as you can make a good mechanical and electrical connection. I have seen this before and it is usually done to save room in the boxes. I haven't seen it in newer installations since the newer codes want at least 6" tail for all devices and 2 wires stretched out to 6" is counterproductive.